# How to put two minipages side-by-side, which use 100 % of the text width?

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment, koma-script, minipage

In `draft`-mode a black marker indicates that the reserved space is too low. This also appears in the following example, but it shouldn't. How can I put two `minipage`s exactly side-by-side?

```
\documentclass[draft=on]{scrbook}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth} %
  TEXT 1
\end{minipage} %
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth} %
  TEXT 2
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You have captured the letter of the law regarding endline `%`'s, but unfortunately missed the spirit.

Comment: @RyanReich You should explain in more details for new users, instead of just pointing it out.

Comment: @paradox I wish I remembered what I meant. Probably that if you're going to use % to remove line breaks, you should do so with code that is sensitive to them.

Comment: @RyanReich This is what I meant : lots of people (me included) know % removes lines breaks but only a few are able to point to a ressource where you can find use-cases where it's necessary. I think this kind of ressources could be helpful to broadcast. Because, like you pointed out, even you could not remember what you meant at the time you answered ;)

Comment: @Paradox That's a reasonable point, but unfortunately, I have been completely out of touch with TeX programming for nearly four years, and I don't know if I could provide any references other than [TeX By Topic](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwicjbaGleXZAhVS7mMKHe6iDjwQFgg1MAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Ftexdoc.net%2Fshow.php%3Fpkg%3Dtexbytopic&usg=AOvVaw0puPbIfW2-5G9IXC7KoeCu), or of course The TeXbook, which is not online (but is worth buying).

Answer (score 91, accepted):

There are two problems in your input.

1. A new paragraph is started with the first minipage, which adds the indent.
2. There is a space between the two minipages.

```
\documentclass[draft=on]{scrbook}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
  TEXT 1
\end{minipage}% This must go next to `\end{minipage}`
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
  TEXT 2
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Note that

```
text %
```

*has* a space after "text", while

```
text%
```

hasn't. The `%` you're using in

```
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth} %
```

does nothing; the end-of-line or spaces after `\begin{minipage}{...}` are ignored anyway. So typing

```
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth} %

\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}%

\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
```

is just the same.

Comment: No space between `\end` and `\begin`, why didn't any one else mention that...

Comment: The space always gets me. Latex shouldn't be that way.