# Signature line with dots and name below

Tags: rules

[image]

In my LaTeX report I want to include a dotted signature line and my name below that line.
As in the image. Can someone help me with the LaTeX code for that?

Comment: It is a matter of simple placements and line breaks. Use the [`minipage`](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Boxes#minipage_and_parbox) environment to contain each of the four items. Use the [`dashrule`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/dashrule) package to get your dotted lines. [This post](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114520/how-to-put-two-minipages-side-by-side-which-use-100-of-the-text-width) might be of some help. You may want to define one or two macros if you want. But I suggest that you do that yourself. Using macros gives you the sweet taste of LaTeX.

Comment: Im really new to latex. Actually I have no idea how they work

Comment: Related: [Dynamic signature/date line](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/48152/5764)

Answer (score 6):

This should get you started.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\sign}[1]{%      
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}
  \makebox[1.5in]{\dotfill}\\
  \strut#1\strut
  \end{tabular}%
}
\newcommand{\Date}{%
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}p{1.5in}@{}}
  \\[-2ex]
  \strut Date: \dotfill\strut
  \end{tabular}%
}


\begin{document}
  \noindent
  \begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\linewidth}
    \raggedright
    \sign{Supervisor}
    \par
    Mr.\,L. L. Silva\par
    Department of Computing and Information Systems, \par
    Faculty of Applied Sciences, \par
    University of Moratuwa
  \end{minipage}%
  \hfill
  \begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\linewidth}
    \sign{Signature of the supervisor}
    \Date
  \end{minipage}


  \vspace{1cm}
  \noindent
  \begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\linewidth}
    \raggedright
    \sign{Head of the Department}
    \par
    Mr.\,M. N. Dias\par
    Department of Computing and Information Systems, \par
    Faculty of Applied Sciences, \par
    University of Moratuwa
  \end{minipage}%
  \hfill
  \begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\linewidth}
    \sign{Signature of Head}
    \Date
  \end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hey thanks for that, that taught me something.