# Placing two tikz figures with captions next to each other

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have drawn two pictures and now I want to place them side by side. I tried using "minipage" but it does not work. Could you help me?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.png,.jpg, .tif}

\usepackage{pgf,tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\usepackage{pgf}


\definecolor{amber}{rgb}{1.0, 0.49, 0.0}

\definecolor{byzantine}{rgb}{0.74, 0.2, 0.64}

\definecolor{royalazure}{rgb}{0.0, 0.22, 0.66}

\definecolor{darkpastelgreen}{rgb}{0.01, 0.75, 0.24}

\definecolor{ashgrey}{rgb}{0.7, 0.75, 0.71}

\begin{document}`

    \begin{figure}[h] % place the figure [h]ere, you may want to give LaTeX some more options
        \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
            \centering
            \scalebox{0.75}{
                \begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm,scale=0.7]
                    \path[fill=darkpastelgreen!70] (5.5,3.5)--(11,7)--(5.5,7)--cycle;
                    \path[fill=amber!70] (0,0)--(5.5,3.5)--(5.5,0)--cycle;
                    \path[fill=byzantine!70] (5.5,0)--(11,0)--(11,7)--(5.5,3.5)--cycle;
                    \path[fill=royalazure!70] (5.5,3.5)--(0,7)--(5.5,7)--cycle;
                    \draw[line width=0.5mm] (0,0) node [below] {A:$(0,0)$} -- (11,0) node [below] {B:$(p,0)$} -- (11,7) node [above] {C:$(p,q)$} -- (0,7) node [above] {D:$(0,q)$} -- (0,0);
                    \draw[line width=0.5mm] (0,0) -- (11,7);
                    \draw[line width=0.5mm] (0,3.5) node [above right] {E:$(0,\frac{q}{2})$} -- (5.5,3.5) node [below right] {F:$(\frac{p}{2},\frac{q}{2})$};
                    \draw[line width=0.5mm] (5.5,3.5) -- (0,7);
                    \draw[line width=0.5mm] (5.5,0) node [below] {G:$(\frac{p}{2},0)$} -- (5.5,7) node [above] {H:$(\frac{p}{2},q)$};
                    \draw[line width=0.5mm] (8.3,5.0) node [below] {$y=\frac{q}{p}x$};
                \end{tikzpicture}
            }
            \caption{The outline of the lattice considered in Eisenstein's proof.}
        \end{minipage}

        \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
            \centering
            \scalebox{0.4}{
                \begin{tikzpicture}
                    \path[draw, line width=0.6mm, fill=ashgrey!25] (0,0) -- (13,0) -- (13,11) -- (0,11) -- (0,0)--cycle;
                    \draw[line width=0.5mm] (0,0) -- (13,11);
                    \draw[line width=0.5mm] (0,5.5) -- (6.5,5.5);
                    \draw[line width=0.5mm] (6.5,0) -- (6.5,11);

                    \draw[dashed, line width=0.0mm, black] (1,0) -- (1,11);
                    \draw[dashed, line width=0.0mm, black] (2,0) -- (2,11);
                    \draw[dashed, line width=0.0mm, black] (3,0) -- (3,11);
                    \draw[dashed, line width=0.0mm, black] (4,0) -- (4,11);
                    \draw[dashed, line width=0.0mm, black] (5,0) -- (5,11);
                    \draw[dashed, line width=0.0mm, black] (6,0) -- (6,11);
                    \draw[dashed, line width=0.0mm, black] (7,0) -- (7,11);
                    \draw[dashed, line width=0.0mm, black] (8,0) -- (8,11);
                    \draw[dashed, line width=0.0mm, black] (9,0) -- (9,11);
                    \draw[dashed, line width=0.0mm, black] (10,0) -- (10,11);
                    \draw[dashed, line width=0.0mm, black] (11,0) -- (11,11);
                    \draw[dashed, line width=0.0mm, black] (12,0) -- (12,11);

                    \draw[dashed, line width=0.0mm, black] (0,1) -- (13,1);
                    \draw[dashed, line width=0.0mm, black] (0,2) -- (13,2);
                    \draw[dashed, line width=0.0mm, black] (0,3) -- (13,3);
                    \draw[dashed, line width=0.0mm, black] (0,4) -- (13,4);
                    \draw[dashed, line width=0.0mm, black] (0,5) -- (13,5);
                    \draw[dashed, line width=0.0mm, black] (0,6) -- (13,6);
                    \draw[dashed, line width=0.0mm, black] (0,7) -- (13,7);
                    \draw[dashed, line width=0.0mm, black] (0,8) -- (13,8);
                    \draw[dashed, line width=0.0mm, black] (0,9) -- (13,9);
                    \draw[dashed, line width=0.0mm, black] (0,10) -- (13,10);


                    \filldraw[byzantine] (8,1) circle (4pt);
                    \filldraw[byzantine] (8,2) circle (4pt);
                    \filldraw[byzantine] (8,3) circle (4pt);
                    \filldraw[byzantine] (8,4) circle (4pt);
                    \filldraw[byzantine] (8,5) circle (4pt);
                    \filldraw[byzantine] (8,6) circle (4pt);
                    \filldraw[byzantine] (8,5) circle (4pt);
                    \filldraw[byzantine] (8,6) circle (4pt);
                    \filldraw[byzantine] (10,1) circle (4pt);
                    \filldraw[byzantine] (10,2) circle (4pt);
                    \filldraw[byzantine] (10,3) circle (4pt);
                    \filldraw[byzantine] (10,4) circle (4pt);
                    \filldraw[byzantine] (10,5) circle (4pt);
                    \filldraw[byzantine] (10,6) circle (4pt);
                    \filldraw[byzantine] (10,7) circle (4pt);
                    \filldraw[byzantine] (10,8) circle (4pt);
                    \filldraw[byzantine] (12,1) circle (4pt);
                    \filldraw[byzantine] (12,2) circle (4pt);
                    \filldraw[byzantine] (12,3) circle (4pt);
                    \filldraw[byzantine] (12,4) circle (4pt);
                    \filldraw[byzantine] (12,5) circle (4pt);
                    \filldraw[byzantine] (12,6) circle (4pt);
                    \filldraw[byzantine] (12,7) circle (4pt);
                    \filldraw[byzantine] (12,8) circle (4pt);
                    \filldraw[byzantine] (12,9) circle (4pt);
                    \filldraw[byzantine] (12,10) circle (4pt);

                    \filldraw[darkpastelgreen] (8,7) circle (4pt);
                    \filldraw[darkpastelgreen] (8,8) circle (4pt);
                    \filldraw[darkpastelgreen] (8,9) circle (4pt);
                    \filldraw[darkpastelgreen] (8,10) circle (4pt);
                    \filldraw[darkpastelgreen] (10,9) circle (4pt);
                    \filldraw[darkpastelgreen] (10,10) circle (4pt);

                    \filldraw[royalazure] (5,7) circle (4pt);
                    \filldraw[royalazure] (5,8) circle (4pt);
                    \filldraw[royalazure] (5,9) circle (4pt);
                    \filldraw[royalazure] (5,10) circle (4pt);
                    \filldraw[royalazure] (3,9) circle (4pt);
                    \filldraw[royalazure] (3,10) circle (4pt);

                    \filldraw[amber] (3,1) circle (4pt);
                    \filldraw[amber] (3,2) circle (4pt);
                    \filldraw[amber] (5,1) circle (4pt);
                    \filldraw[amber] (5,2) circle (4pt);
                    \filldraw[amber] (5,3) circle (4pt);
                    \filldraw[amber] (5,4) circle (4pt);
                \end{tikzpicture}
            }
            \caption{The lattice used in Eisenstein's proof in case $p=13$ and $q=11$.}
        \end{minipage}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Just have to remove the space between end of first minipage and begining of second mnipage. See this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/157222/putting-figures-side-by-side-using-minipage and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114520/how-to-put-two-minipages-side-by-side-which-use-100-of-the-text-width

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just enclose your codes into an another `minipage` tags will solve the issue:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.png,.jpg, .tif}

\usepackage{pgf,tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\usepackage{pgf}


\definecolor{amber}{rgb}{1.0, 0.49, 0.0}

\definecolor{byzantine}{rgb}{0.74, 0.2, 0.64}

\definecolor{royalazure}{rgb}{0.0, 0.22, 0.66}

\definecolor{darkpastelgreen}{rgb}{0.01, 0.75, 0.24}

\definecolor{ashgrey}{rgb}{0.7, 0.75, 0.71}

\begin{document}`

    \begin{figure}[h] % place the figure [h]ere, you may want to give LaTeX some more options
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
        \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
            \centering
            \scalebox{0.75}{
                \begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm,scale=0.7]
                    \path[fill=darkpastelgreen!70] (5.5,3.5)--(11,7)--(5.5,7)--cycle;
                    \path[fill=amber!70] (0,0)--(5.5,3.5)--(5.5,0)--cycle;
                    \path[fill=byzantine!70] (5.5,0)--(11,0)--(11,7)--(5.5,3.5)--cycle;
                    \path[fill=royalazure!70] (5.5,3.5)--(0,7)--(5.5,7)--cycle;
                    \draw[line width=0.5mm] (0,0) node [below] {A:$(0,0)$} -- (11,0) node [below] {B:$(p,0)$} -- (11,7) node [above] {C:$(p,q)$} -- (0,7) node [above] {D:$(0,q)$} -- (0,0);
                    \draw[line width=0.5mm] (0,0) -- (11,7);
                    \draw[line width=0.5mm] (0,3.5) node [above right] {E:$(0,\frac{q}{2})$} -- (5.5,3.5) node [below right] {F:$(\frac{p}{2},\frac{q}{2})$};
                    \draw[line width=0.5mm] (5.5,3.5) -- (0,7);
                    \draw[line width=0.5mm] (5.5,0) node [below] {G:$(\frac{p}{2},0)$} -- (5.5,7) node [above] {H:$(\frac{p}{2},q)$};
                    \draw[line width=0.5mm] (8.3,5.0) node [below] {$y=\frac{q}{p}x$};
                \end{tikzpicture}
            }
            \caption{The outline of the lattice considered in Eisenstein's proof.}
        \end{minipage}
\hskip12pt
        \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
            \centering
            \scalebox{0.4}{
                \begin{tikzpicture}
                    \path[draw, line width=0.6mm, fill=ashgrey!25] (0,0) -- (13,0) -- (13,11) -- (0,11) -- (0,0)--cycle;
                    \draw[line width=0.5mm] (0,0) -- (13,11);
                    \draw[line width=0.5mm] (0,5.5) -- (6.5,5.5);
                    \draw[line width=0.5mm] (6.5,0) -- (6.5,11);

                    \draw[dashed, line width=0.0mm, black] (1,0) -- (1,11);
                    \draw[dashed, line width=0.0mm, black] (2,0) -- (2,11);
                    \draw[dashed, line width=0.0mm, black] (3,0) -- (3,11);
                    \draw[dashed, line width=0.0mm, black] (4,0) -- (4,11);
                    \draw[dashed, line width=0.0mm, black] (5,0) -- (5,11);
                    \draw[dashed, line width=0.0mm, black] (6,0) -- (6,11);
                    \draw[dashed, line width=0.0mm, black] (7,0) -- (7,11);
                    \draw[dashed, line width=0.0mm, black] (8,0) -- (8,11);
                    \draw[dashed, line width=0.0mm, black] (9,0) -- (9,11);
                    \draw[dashed, line width=0.0mm, black] (10,0) -- (10,11);
                    \draw[dashed, line width=0.0mm, black] (11,0) -- (11,11);
                    \draw[dashed, line width=0.0mm, black] (12,0) -- (12,11);

                    \draw[dashed, line width=0.0mm, black] (0,1) -- (13,1);
                    \draw[dashed, line width=0.0mm, black] (0,2) -- (13,2);
                    \draw[dashed, line width=0.0mm, black] (0,3) -- (13,3);
                    \draw[dashed, line width=0.0mm, black] (0,4) -- (13,4);
                    \draw[dashed, line width=0.0mm, black] (0,5) -- (13,5);
                    \draw[dashed, line width=0.0mm, black] (0,6) -- (13,6);
                    \draw[dashed, line width=0.0mm, black] (0,7) -- (13,7);
                    \draw[dashed, line width=0.0mm, black] (0,8) -- (13,8);
                    \draw[dashed, line width=0.0mm, black] (0,9) -- (13,9);
                    \draw[dashed, line width=0.0mm, black] (0,10) -- (13,10);


                    \filldraw[byzantine] (8,1) circle (4pt);
                    \filldraw[byzantine] (8,2) circle (4pt);
                    \filldraw[byzantine] (8,3) circle (4pt);
                    \filldraw[byzantine] (8,4) circle (4pt);
                    \filldraw[byzantine] (8,5) circle (4pt);
                    \filldraw[byzantine] (8,6) circle (4pt);
                    \filldraw[byzantine] (8,5) circle (4pt);
                    \filldraw[byzantine] (8,6) circle (4pt);
                    \filldraw[byzantine] (10,1) circle (4pt);
                    \filldraw[byzantine] (10,2) circle (4pt);
                    \filldraw[byzantine] (10,3) circle (4pt);
                    \filldraw[byzantine] (10,4) circle (4pt);
                    \filldraw[byzantine] (10,5) circle (4pt);
                    \filldraw[byzantine] (10,6) circle (4pt);
                    \filldraw[byzantine] (10,7) circle (4pt);
                    \filldraw[byzantine] (10,8) circle (4pt);
                    \filldraw[byzantine] (12,1) circle (4pt);
                    \filldraw[byzantine] (12,2) circle (4pt);
                    \filldraw[byzantine] (12,3) circle (4pt);
                    \filldraw[byzantine] (12,4) circle (4pt);
                    \filldraw[byzantine] (12,5) circle (4pt);
                    \filldraw[byzantine] (12,6) circle (4pt);
                    \filldraw[byzantine] (12,7) circle (4pt);
                    \filldraw[byzantine] (12,8) circle (4pt);
                    \filldraw[byzantine] (12,9) circle (4pt);
                    \filldraw[byzantine] (12,10) circle (4pt);

                    \filldraw[darkpastelgreen] (8,7) circle (4pt);
                    \filldraw[darkpastelgreen] (8,8) circle (4pt);
                    \filldraw[darkpastelgreen] (8,9) circle (4pt);
                    \filldraw[darkpastelgreen] (8,10) circle (4pt);
                    \filldraw[darkpastelgreen] (10,9) circle (4pt);
                    \filldraw[darkpastelgreen] (10,10) circle (4pt);

                    \filldraw[royalazure] (5,7) circle (4pt);
                    \filldraw[royalazure] (5,8) circle (4pt);
                    \filldraw[royalazure] (5,9) circle (4pt);
                    \filldraw[royalazure] (5,10) circle (4pt);
                    \filldraw[royalazure] (3,9) circle (4pt);
                    \filldraw[royalazure] (3,10) circle (4pt);

                    \filldraw[amber] (3,1) circle (4pt);
                    \filldraw[amber] (3,2) circle (4pt);
                    \filldraw[amber] (5,1) circle (4pt);
                    \filldraw[amber] (5,2) circle (4pt);
                    \filldraw[amber] (5,3) circle (4pt);
                    \filldraw[amber] (5,4) circle (4pt);
                \end{tikzpicture}
            }
            \caption{The lattice used in Eisenstein's proof in case $p=13$ and $q=11$.}
        \end{minipage}
\end{minipage}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.